# Static variables and functions usage

Tags: c++, static-variables, static-functions

I have the following class definition and the main(). Can someone please point me why I am getting the error?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

class test
{
protected:
  static list<int> a;
public:
  test()
  {
    a.push_back(150);
  }
  static void send(int c)
  {
    if (c==1)
      cout<<a.front()<<endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  test c;
  test::send(1);
  return 0;
}
```

The error that I get is as follows:

```
/tmp/ccre4um4.o: In function `test::test()':
test_static.cpp:(.text._ZN4testC1Ev[test::test()]+0x1b): undefined reference to `test::a'
/tmp/ccre4um4.o: In function `test::send(int)':
test_static.cpp:(.text._ZN4test4sendEi[test::send(int)]+0x12): undefined reference to `test::a'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The error is same even if I use c.send(1) instead of test::send(1). Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've *declared* `test::a`, but you haven't *defined* it. Add the definition in namespace scope:

```
list<int> test::a;
```

Comment: Sorry. I did not understand. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Neel : What would you expect to happen if you declared a function `void foo();` but called it without defining it? Clearly such a thing cannot work. The same goes for static data members -- declaring them is not sufficient, they must also be defined. My answer shows the syntax for that definition.

Comment: Thank you. I got it. Even after so many years of working with C++, I never recollect having done anything like this for static variables. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

a is declared but must still be defined.
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.12